# Iterating over the types in a boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, boost-variant

I'm using a boost variant to hold some generated types, right now my code generator creates a header with the types and a variant capable of holding them.  At initialization time, I'd like to iterate over the allowable types in the variant, not the types the variant is holding at the moment.

Can I do this with a variant?

Comment: Iterating over the types to do what?

Comment: I need to populate a map<string, MyVariant>.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`boost::variant` exposes its types via `types`, which is an MPL list. You can do runtime operations over MPL lists using [mpl::for_each](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/for-each.html):

```
struct printer {
    template<class T> void operator()(T t) {
        std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    }
};

// ... 
typedef boost::variant<int, char> var;
boost::mpl::for_each<var::types>(printer());
```

Comment: might need `boost::mpl::make_identity<>` when some of the types are not default constructible.